# html2canvas: Error Uncaught (in promise): [object undefined] angular 6

Tags: html, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas, xhtml2pdf

I am using html2canvas to convert html to image, then export as pdf file. Here is my steps using this package:

1. yarn add html2canvas
2. add code to convert html to image.

   ```
   async export(comp, doc, save) {
     // create pdf file
     let height = REPORT_PAGE.top;
     const header = comp.reportHeader.nativeElement;
     const headerCanvas = await html2canvas(header, {svgRendering: true});
     height = REPORT_PAGE.top;
     let imgHeightHtml = REPORT_PAGE.header * REPORT_PAGE.width / headerCanvas.width;
     let contentDataURL = headerCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
     doc.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', REPORT_PAGE.left, height, REPORT_PAGE.width, imgHeightHtml);
     if (save) {
       doc.save('myreport.pdf');
     } else {
       doc.addPage();
     }
   }
   ```

where comp is the angular component, doc is jsPDF, save is boolean. The following error will throw when the html2canvas is called.

```
Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined]
at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
at zone.js:873
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4053)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:500)
at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
```

html2canvas is a very useful package, but this error is really bad. Please help.

Comment: `export` is a reserved word, just fyi.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and this fixed it:

```
html2canvas(element, {
    ignoreElements: (node) => {
        return node.nodeName === 'IFRAME';
    }
}).then((canvas) => {
    ...
});
```

source: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1593#issuecomment-489059452

Answer (score 2):

I have also run into the same issue and concluded that it is a bug. After a quick search, I came across this thread:

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1593

...where a user (adamszeibert) pointed out the responsible piece of code:

> I've found that in my case the error was coming from iframeLoader defined in https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/src/Clone.js at around line 572.
>
> I could solve the issue by changing the code to return Promise.resolve(cloneIframeContainer);
>   I'm pretty sure this fix breaks a lots of other uses cases, but for what I needed it solved the issue.

### Solution 1:

As of today, there is an open pull request for the solution:

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/pull/1681

### Solution 2:

Use runOutsideAngular method of NgZone.

**Step 1:**
Import NgZone from Angular Core:

```
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core';
```

**Step 2:**
Add ngZone to component constructor:

```
  constructor(
              ...
              ...
              private _ngZone: NgZone) {
                  ...
              }
```

**Step 3:**
Encapsulate your html2canvas code as follows:

```
  public saveAsImage = () => {

    this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

        html2canvas(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]).then(canvas => {
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
            a.download = 'Some Filename.jpg';
            a.click();
          });
    });
  };
```

Comment: 1. Solution 2 doesn't work. 2. I will wait for the open PR is incorporated in a build.

Comment: do you have a link to the open PR? This is an issue for me as well